# How to make dynamic font property based on condition for textField in jasper report?

Tags: jasper-reports

I would like to make a dynamic change font property based on variable condition.

I have already searched on the stackoverflow's questions but I didn't find anything for this detail.

Below my snippet code:

```
    <textField>
      <reportElement style="DetailsPrice" x="370" y="5" width="56" height="15" uuid="2f0dc291-6a8b-48d3-b7d1-fe931b88e859">
        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.y" value="px"/>
        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.x" value="mm"/>
        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="mm"/>
          <printWhenExpression>
             <![CDATA[$F{product_unformatted_discount_amount} != null && $F{product_unformatted_discount_amount} != 0]]>
          </printWhenExpression>
      </reportElement>
      <textElement textAlignment="Left" verticalAlignment="Middle">
         <font isBold="true" isStrikeThrough="true"/>
      </textElement>
        <textFieldExpression><![CDATA["+" + $F{product_price_formatted_amount}]]></textFieldExpression>
    </textField>
```

How can I change ***isStrikeThrough*** property value depending on $F{product_unformatted_discount_amount} value ?
In a nutshell I would like to apply condition in line in the *font* tag.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I resolved via ***markup*** tag with styled value.

Markup [documentation](https://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/sample.reference/markup/index.html)

code snippet:

```
<textElement textAlignment="Left" verticalAlignment="Middle" markup="styled"/>
<textFieldExpression>
      <![CDATA[$F{product_unformatted_discount_amount} != null && $F{product_unformatted_discount_amount} != 0 ? "<style isStrikeThrough='true' isBold='true'> +" + $F{product_price_formatted_amount} + "</style>" : "<style isStrikeThrough='false' isBold='true'> +" + $F{product_price_formatted_amount} + "</style>"]]>
</textFieldExpression>
```

I put the *markup* tag with ***styled*** value into *textElement* tag, while *isStrikeThrough* tag in the *textFieldExpression* tag implementing if inline

> **markup=styled** This markup is capable to format the text using a set of
> HTML-like tags and it is pretty popular in the Java environments. It
> allows to set a specific font for chunks of text, color, background,
> style and so on. It's often good enough to format the text
> programmatically.